# How can i configure WAVES Client to use TESTNET?

Tags: wavesplatform

I need to create a token in TESTNET. I launched the Waves client but i cannot see any option to switch to TESTNET Network. Is there a way to configure WAVES client so i can create or use wallets in TESTNET and then create tokens, try leasing etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes sure, just go to this link https://testnet.wavesplatform.com
then you can use Waves Client on testnet.